# TypeError: api.tx.balances.transfer is not a function substrate contracts node

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, polkadot

`api.tx.balances.transfer` was working perfectly some time ago. I tried to re-run my testcase today and I'm getting this error.

```
const rawTX = api.tx.balances.transfer(alice.address, 30)
                              ^
TypeError: api.tx.balances.transfer is not a function
```

I didn't change anything here. I'm connecting to the local substrate node but have also tested with Rococo RPC wss://rococo-contracts-rpc.polkadot.io

what is the issue here, I didn't even upgrade the polkadot version. My current version is

```
"@polkadot/api": "10.9.1"
```

I'm out of ideas any help is appreciated.

here's the code snippet

```
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
    await api.isReady
    const keyring = new Keyring({type: 'sr25519'})
    const alice = keyring.createFromUri('//Alice')
    const rawTX = api.tx.balances.transfer(alice.address, 30)
    console.log(rawTX)
```

UPDATE: I tracked the issue, I had rebuilt the docker image that is using the [substrate node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node), I checked my code with old image and its working fine but with the new image the issue still persists. I still don't know why is this happening and I cannot use my old image as it doesn't have healthcheck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since Polkadot v0.9.42 `Balances::transfer` has been renamed to `Balances::transfer_allow_death`  ([PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12951)). This means you now have to either use `api.tx.balances.transferAllowDeath` or `api.tx.balances.transferKeepAlive`! :)

**For reference, see the [transfer-helpers](https://github.com/scio-labs/use-inkathon/blob/main/src/helpers/transferBalance.ts) in our [useInkathon library](https://github.com/scio-labs/use-inkathon).**

Comment: This problem is also in py-substrate-interface and exactly changing the call_function:transfer to call_function:transfer_allow_death solves the problem,
Thank you.